# View container breaks my code

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am trying to implement a layout for a titanium alloy application. This is my code so far:

> `<Alloy>`
>
> > ```
> > <Window class="container">`
> >       <View id="containerView" class="container" layout="vertical">
> >         <View id="navBarView" layout='horizontal'>
> >               <Button id="id" onClick="doClick" title="title" width="50%"height="50dp"/>
> >               <Button id="id1" onClick="doClick" title="title" width="50%" height="50"/>
> >           </View>       
> >         <!-- Here are several labels which should be grouped vertically --> 
> >       </View>
> > </Window> </Alloy>
> > ```

(Sorry for the bad formatting)

If I delete the containerView the labels are displayed but centered vertically. I want them to be displayed directly after the navBarView. When I run the code as it is it does not display any labels at all. My navBarView works as excepted all the time.

I am thankful for every input, I am new to titanium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the `width & heigth & top` for exemple in your tss file :

```
"#navBarView":{
       height:'20%',
       top:0,
       width:'100%'
 }
".yourlabelContainer":{
     height:'80%',
     layout:'vertical',
     width:'100%'
}
".mylabel":{
     font:{
        fontSize:19,
        fontWeight:'bold'
     },
     color:'#000'
     height:'20%' //(100/5)
}
```

and in xml file :

```
<Alloy>
   <Window class="container">`
      <View id="containerView" class="container" layout="vertical">
        <View id="navBarView" layout='horizontal'>
          <Button id="id" onClick="doClick" title="title" width="50%"height="50dp"/>
          <Button id="id1" onClick="doClick" title="title" width="50%" height="50"/>
        </View>
        <View calss="yourlabelContainer">
           <Label class="mylabel>Lab1</Label>
           <Label class="mylabel>Lab2</Label>
           <Label class="mylabel>Lab3</Label>
           <Label class="mylabel>Lab4</Label>
           <Label class="mylabel>Lab5</Label>
        </View>   
       </View>
    </Window> 
</Alloy>
```